# Different behaviour of "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob" and "Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob"

Tags: .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm writing a .NET Azure Function App that needs to access an Azure Blob Storage. Microsoft provides the libraries `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` and `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` for exactly that purpose, whereas `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` is the more current one that should therefore be used. However the behaviour seems to be different and I don't understand why or what I need to do differently.

I keep on getting StorageExceptions referring to wrong Http Headers when using `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` that didn't occur with the older package.

Here is a code snippet that generally should work with both libraries:

```
var blobStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("{connectionString}");
var blobClient = blobStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container123");
var exists = await blobContainer.ExistsAsync();
```

The output should be true or false, what works perfectly with `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` but with `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob`, I keep on getting StorageExceptions with the message "The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format." when the `ExistsAsync()` method is called. The creation of the CloudBlobClient works just fine in both libraries.

Obviously there is a simple solution - use the old package. But that isn't really satisfying since I'd like to use up-to-date libraries.

Has anyone experienced similar issues?

Edit:
I must have made another error somewhere else. I have turned to the new lib again and it worked all of a sudden. I *guess* I messed up to really change all references in all classes of the code.

Comment: it's function v2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started a clean Console App (.NET Core) and followed these steps:

1. Copied your code into `Main` (and made it an `async Task`)
2. Added a reference to Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob (V 11.0.0)
3. Pasted a connection string for one of my Storage accounts
4. Ran the console app

The result: it just works fine.

I guess we'll need a bit more information, although I do have some ideas:

- Are you using a 'full' connection string, or one with an SAS token?
- Do you have (the right) rights to the storage account?

Feels to me like you have a connection string with a SAS token that doesn't allow you to check if a container exists.

**EDIT**
I just checked with a connection string with a SAS token that *doesn't* have rights on container level. That throws an exception with message:

> This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this resource type.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue considering same code using different SDK works.